# Software package invisible.Package jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm has set up a module in Java

Tags: java

Package jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm has set up a module in Java. Declared in the module Java.base,but not the module to export it to unnamed module.Has anyone ever met this mistake?seek help.

Comment: Hi, could you restate what exactly you are trying and what are the error messages you are seeing? Are you using Intellij?

Comment: I try to use gradle CompileJava, but package jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm invisible @MingweiSamuel

Comment: Can you copy and paste an error message here?

Comment: Error: package jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm invisible
import jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm.*;
(package jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm has set up a module in Java. The base of the statement, but not the module to export it to unnamed module). like this.     @MingweiSamuel

Comment: Perfect problem solving!!! Very thankful ! @matt